# Wrapping a parallel C++ file using boost.MPI to support python mpi4py

Tags: python, c++, boost, mpi, mpi4py

I have a C++ file xxx.cpp which is written in Boost MPI (for C++), and due to some reasons, I need to run this C++ code in a mpi4py environment (the C++ code provides calculation for one part of the python code.). What I want to do is:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
from subprocess import check_call, CalledProcessError

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

if rank == 0:
    cmd = "mpirun -np n ./xxx ${input_file}"
    check_call(cmd, shell=True)
```

However, this isn't able to run because mpirun cannot be nested in another mpirun. But I still want to run the xxx (binary of xxx.cpp) in parallel while in the mpi4py environment.

Hence, I am searching for a way to connect the mpi communicator of mpi4py with Boost::mpi, in order to run the cpp file in parallel. Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: Your example has no MPI in the python code. Is there going to be any? Try starting your `xxx` program sequentially, but from every python MPI rank. Usually the `mpirun` program sets all the environment variables correctly.  Your next problem is then going to be that python already does the MPI init, so you should skip it in the `xxx` program.

Comment: I omitted the MPI part in the python code. In fact, the whole python program is parallelized using mpi4py, hence there will be interference bewteen these mpirun's.  However, running C++ sequentially while running python in parallel does not significantly accelerate the program, since the C++ code was originally written in Boost::mpi and was elaborately optimized. So what I want to do is to control the parallel tasks in C++ at python level using mpi4py, but I didn't find any interfaces between Boost::mpi and mpi4py.

Comment: I'm not saying running C++ sequentially: I say *starting* it once from each python MPI process. With a little luck it will act as like a parallel run where MPI was already initialized. Alternatively, use `MPI_Comm_spawn`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite understand "starting it once from each python MPI process", could you please provide some pseudo code or more precise descriptions?